# Check if another function is in action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native, recursion

I using **react-select** to filter tags on my applications.
So, whenever users input tags, it will generate keyword according to the tags that inputted by the user.

let's says my tags are like this:

[image]

So, it will be generated with cat and fish keyword.

And in my selectfield which is I using **react-select**, the tags will automatically be added in my selectfield, like this:

[image]

That already done in my app.

What I want now are, filter the tags that the users inputted with selectfield, so whenever users select cat, it will just showing cat keywords.

The tags above are generated by this function, which is just snippet of my code:

```
onSubmit = tags => {
  if(tags.length === 0) {
    userError('Please input at least one keyword');
  } else {
    tags.forEach((tag) => {
      const marketplace = selectedCountry.value;
      apiCallRequest(marketplace, tag.value, this.userIP);
      if (this.handleChange()){  // call handleChange function here
        apiCallRequest(marketplace, tag.value=this.state.selectedOption, this.userIP);
        alert('hello from here :)')
        return onsubmit
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The purpose of function above are for generates keyword from the tags that inputted by users.

And my **react-select** code are like [Installation and usage](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), which is just the sample code from documentions:

```
handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  }
```

There `handleChange()` called by **onChange** even.

So, in this case, whenever users selected one of the selectfield, it will call the `handleChange()` function.

So, what I want here are, whenever the functions is calling, I want the `onSubmit` function also takes it changes automatically.

So, is it posiblle to do that..?
I hope my questions clearer now, if no I will edit it again :)

Comment: What do you mean by "in action"?

Comment: what do you mean by `I want to check if the function is in actions` ?

Comment: I call the `handleChange()` with `onChange` even, so whenever the `onChange()` takes action in it function, the `onSubmit()` also takes the changes automatically.

Comment: still don't get it

Comment: Ok, I will add more descriptive questions, wait a minute :)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and what you really want to do is validate `this.state.selectedOption` before making request in onSubmit

Comment: @charlietfl - I was thinking it sounded like an X/Y problem as well.

Comment: Calling handleChange() with no parameters doesn't make sense. What higher level problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: You keep fiddling with edits of the `X` in your  *XY Problem* and not explaining the `Y` which requires a properly written problem statement. Nobody can help you if you don't explain your actual problem or exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Ok @charlietfl, I will edit it again and add more descriptive with my actual problem

Comment: I have edited @charlietfl, I hope it more clearer now :)

Comment: Not really .. still confusing why you want to call handle change in the loop. Are you getting data from api request you want added to the select?

Answer (score 2):

On browsers (and most other JavaScript host environments), there's only a single thread per *realm* (a global environment and associated intrinsic objects, etc., like the JavaScript environment associated with a browser window). Assuming `handleChange` and `onSubmit` are in the same realm (which I'm sure they are), if your `onSubmit` function is running, you know that your `handleChange` function is not running, because `handleChange` does not call `onSubmit`. The only way `handleChange` could be "active" when `onSubmit` is "active" is if `handleChange` called `onSubmit`.